# How to make custom SEO url in opencart?

Tags: url, seo, opencart

I'm trying to make my custom URLs but having some troubles (Opencart 1.5.3.1). I want the category page to be

http://myshop.com/category_id if I don't have SEO keyword for category in admin panel

OR

http://myshop.com/category_seo_keyword if I have entered SEO keyword for category

and my product page to be

http://myshop.com/category_seo_keyword/product_id

where {product_id} is always "product-" + "product id, not model". I don't want to display SEO keyword for product even if it's entered in admin panel.

for example http://myshop.com/cameras/product-13

Any ideas?

Comment: Short of creating a new url rewriting class, you won't be able to do this. You need to consider how the cart can tell the difference between an ID being for a category and a product too. I created a mod called "Uber SEO URL's" - can be purchased from the OC extension store, that does something vaguely similar to what you want

Comment: ok, how about making them just category-id/product-id ?

Comment: again, it's going to require you rewriting the url class completely to your own

Answer (score 0):

A simple "no code" method is to install vQmod. Instructions here: [vQmod install wiki](https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/wiki/Install_OpenCart)

And then upload the xml file available in this [Opencart forum thread](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=89805&p=362757&hilit=seo%20account#p363224) to the `vqmod/xml/ folder`.

The xml contains a relatively easy to read script that maps the urls similar to the two answers above, but without modifying core files. So site updates will not kill it.